# Are there any dumbbell exercises equivalent to the basic squat?

Tags: weightlifting, squats

I'm considering buying a good set of dumbbell weights (pro tip: get them on craigslist) and a bench so that I can work out at home. However, I'm a big fan of the squat, but I don't want to have to also buy an olympic weight bar and plates. Are there any exercises that can be performed with dumbbells that are mostly equivalent to the squat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image] [image]

Here's a link to a video and info for [a standard dumbbell squat:](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/dumbbell-squat), you probably want to also look into front squats and overhead squats utilizing dumbbells.

Comment: I've done the front squat with dumbbells in a hotel gym.  I prefer the load higher up so I can strengthen the core more.  Squats are not meant to be simply a leg exercise.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking that if I want to do a proper squat I'm just gonna have to get the barbell... this doesn't engage the back and core the same way as a standard squat.

Comment: @Eykanal - as Berin mentioned a front squat (and definitely an overhead squat) will hit the core hard

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice. That looks promising.

Comment: @Meade care to summarize what front squats and overhead squats should look like?

Answer (score 0):

There are many one-legged squats and many require use of a bench. I like using dumbbells with a split-squat while having the rear leg on a bench. Very challenging and can be done when you don't have heavy weights available.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a video or description of technique?

Comment: @eykanal Videos aren't accessible during business hours. I'll link one in later.

Comment: A detailed explanation would probably do as well (just saying)